# X value of 2020 year is greater than Y value of 2021 and so on. how to write python code for this logic using pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

X value of 2020 year is greater than Y value of 2021 and so on. how to write python code for this logic using pandas data frame

for instance:
X value of current year FY+0 is greater than Y value for the Next year FY+1, those details should list down as result

below is the input dataset:
tag_x   peo value_x tag_y   value_y
0   X   3/31/2019   10000   Y   11000
1   X   6/30/2019   12000   Y   9000
2   X   3/31/2020   11000   Y   12000
3   X   6/30/2020   13000   Y   10000
4   X   3/31/2021   12000   Y   13000
5   X   6/30/2021   14000   Y   11000

i should get output like " X value of 3/31/2019 peo is greater than Y value of 6/30/2019 peo"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.head().to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: 2020 2021 2022
X 7 4 11
Y 2 6 3

Comment: ''' 2020 2021 2022
X 7 4 11
Y 2 6 3
'''

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
   2020  2021  2022
X     7     4    11
Y     2     6     3
```

You can use `shift` to compare the X row and the next values in the Y row:

```
df.loc['X'].gt(df.loc['Y'].shift(-1))[:-1]
```

output:

```
2020     True        # X(2020) > Y(2021)
2021     True        # X(2021) > Y(2022)
Name: Y, dtype: bool
```

Comment: C means dataset?

Comment: using below data set....can you tell me how to implement above logic?

Comment: No, it was a typo, C should have been X

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74068545/edit) the question, formatting is not preserved in comments

Comment: Also provide more rows in your example and give the matching expected output

Comment: question edited above

Comment: You didn't provide the expected output

Comment: plz check i have edited question